# Exchange objects between c++ and java using json

Tags: java, c++, json, spring, qt

I am trying exchange data stored  on objects from a c++/qt project to java/spring using websockets and json. the communication via websockets are working fine, but in the java/spring the data arrives as `null`.

in the c++ class, i have something like that:

```
QString Usuario::toString() {
    QString json = "{'email': "+email+"}";
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8());
    QByteArray prettyPrintedJson = document.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
    return prettyPrintedJson;
}
```

for classes like that:

**usuario.h**

```
class Usuario
{
private:
    QString email;
public:
    Usuario();
    Usuario(QString email);

    QString getEmail();
    void setEmail(QString email);

    QString toString();
};
```

**registro.h**

```
class Registro
{
private:
    QString token;
    Usuario usuario;
    Produto produto;
    Maquina maquina;
public:
    Registro();
    Registro(QString token, Usuario usuario, Produto produto, Maquina maquina);
    Registro(Usuario usuario, Produto produto, Maquina maquina);

    QString getToken();
    void setToken(QString token);

    Usuario getUsuario();
    void setUsuario(Usuario usuario);

    Produto getProduto();
    void setProduto(Produto produto);

    Maquina getMaquina();
    void setMaquina(Maquina maquina);

    QString toString();
};
```

in the java project, I have something like this:

```
@Component
public class CheckRegistro extends TextWebSocketHandler {
...
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Registro value = new Gson().fromJson(message.getPayload(), Registro.class);
    System.out.println("registro -> " + value);

    String email_usuario = value.getUsuario().getEmail();
    Usuario usuario = usuarioServ.findBy("email", email_usuario);

    String nome_produto = value.getProduto().getNome();
    Produto produto = produtoServ.findBy("nome", nome_produto);

    Cliente cliente = clienteServ.findBy("usuario", usuario);
    if(cliente.produtosComprados().contains(produto))
      value = registroServ.findBy("produto", produto);

    String result = new Gson().toJson(value);
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(result));
    }
...
}
```

and classes like that:

**usuario.java**

```
@Entity
public class Usuario extends Model implements UserDetails {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String username;

  @Column
  private String password;

  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;

  @Column
  private String email;
...
}
```

**registro.java**

```
@Entity
public class Registro extends Model{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String token;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Usuario usuario;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Produto produto;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Maquina maquina;
...
}
```

(for the record, some classes, like `usuario` have more fields in java than c++; others, like `registro` have the same fields either on the c++ side or in the java side).

someone can hint me what's wrong here? I know there is some libraries that can serialize the c++ object into json automatically, but I dunno if it's possible do that without add a third-party component to my project, just finding the right format for the string sent to the java socket.

**update**

I change the `toString` method in the c++ side to something like that:

```
QString Registro::toString() {
    QJsonObject json{
      { "token", token },
      { "usuario", usuario.toString() },
      { "produto", produto.toString() },
      { "maquina", maquina.toString() }
    };
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc;
    jsonDoc.setObject(json);
    QByteArray prettyPrintedJson = jsonDoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
    return prettyPrintedJson;
}
```

and now, in the java side, the json  string is printed like that:

```
"registro": "{\n    \"maquina\": \"{\\n    \\\"cpuArch\\\": \\\"x86_64\\\",\\n    \\\"hostName\\\": \\\"DESKTOP-7GAPC4K\\\",\\n    \\\"kernelType\\\": \\\"windows\\\",\\n    \\\"kernelVersion\\\": \\\"10\\\",\\n    \\\"productName\\\": \\\"Windows 10 Version 1909\\\",\\n    \\\"ram\\\": \\\"RAM: 16030 MB\\\",\\n    \\\"uniqueId\\\": \\\"c69d8cc7-8e66-4ea3-964a-792b2c2a6f80\\\"\\n}\\n\",\n    \"produto\": \"{\\n    \\\"nome\\\": \\\"prod1\\\"\\n}\\n\",\n    \"token\": \"\",\n    \"usuario\": \"{\\n    \\\"email\\\": \\\"klebermo@gmail.com\\\"\\n}\\n\"\n}\n"
}
```

**update 2**

I change the method `toString` in the c++ side to something like that:

```
QString Registro::toString() {
    return "{ \"token\": \""+token+"\", \"usuario\": "+usuario.toString()+", \"produto\": "+produto.toString()+", \"maquina\": "+maquina.toString()+" }";
}
```

and now in the java side I get a valid json, but here:

```
Registro value = new Gson().fromJson(message.getPayload(), Registro.class);

String email_usuario = value.getUsuario().getEmail();
Usuario usuario = usuarioServ.findBy("email", email_usuario);

String nome_produto = value.getProduto().getNome();
Produto produto = produtoServ.findBy("nome", nome_produto);
```

I am geting a `NullPointerException` for `value.getUsuario().getEmail()`. I really need send a class from the c++ side with all the fields from the java class?  Is there any way to allow me send only the class with fields needed for this query? Or this is not the problem?

Comment: print the string that arrives to the java end, and see if  it's a valid json string

Comment: You may think there isn't much value in using a proper JSON library, but this sure looks like you could use one. Additionally, you might something like protocolbuffers or flatbuffers more to your liking.

Comment: Step 1 when having two programs communicate, is to specify the exact format of the data, i.e. the JSON. I don't mean "JSON", but `{ "foo": "Hello", "bar": 42 }`. So what JSON text do you expect to be transmitted? --- Step 2 when researching deserialization issues it to verify you get the JSON text you expected. --- Step 3 is to test how the receiver would generate the JSON text, i.e. build test data in Java with those classes and generate JSON, to verify that the classes match the expected JSON.

Comment: Your biggest question right now should be: is my client wrong or is my server wrong? That's why it helps to test a new server manually first, by sending it some hand-made JSON that you know is correct, before testing TWO new components together. Use a debugger to visually inspect the input before and after the call `new Gson().fromJson`.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

`json` in `Usuario::toString` is not valid JSON. `QJsonDocument::fromJson` returns `null` when parsing fails.

Assuming `email` is not quoted you need:

```
QString json = "{\"email\": \""+email+"\"}";
```

Alternatively, safer and simpler would be to use the JSON API:

```
QJsonObject json{
  { "email", email }
};
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
QByteArray prettyPrintedJson = document.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
```

Comment: I have tri that before the code I posted, and got the same result. I actually use something like `return "{...}";` first, and because do not working try `QJsonDocument` and `QJsonObject` parsing the string before return to see if would return the correct json string.

Comment: Please post a [mre] with the exact code you've tried, you might want to put some error checking in as well, `QJsonDocument::fromJson` failing to parse seems like the most likely suspect

Comment: Also I print the json string before try convert to java objct in the java side, and arrives everything, the `\` included, but after the `Registro value = new Gson().fromJson(message.getPayload(), Registro.class);` the object gets `null` value.